# Mocking a next function with 2 arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am trying to mock `https.get` with is nested in my custom function `getSecureString()`. `https.get` returns two json elements which `getSecureString()` uses in its try/catch section. See functions below.

Online version at https://repl.it/@SandraSchlichti/jest-playground-4#getSecureString.test.js

The error I am getting is

```
Expected: 1
Received: undefined

  25 | 
  26 |     it('should return 1', () => {
> 27 |       expect(result).toEqual(1)
     |                      ^
  28 |     })
  29 |   });
  30 | 

  at Object.<anonymous> (getSecureString.test.js:27:22)
```

where I would have expected the test to break as I haven't included the mocked `res.statusCode: 200` response from `https.get()` yet.

**getSecureString.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
var uuid = require('uuid');
const {v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid');

module.exports = async function getSecureString(options) {
  options            = options || {};
  options.hostname   = options.hostname || {};
  options.path       = options.path || '/';
  options.string     = options.string || {};
  options.statusCode = options.statusCode || {};
  options.aftaleId   = options.aftaleId || {};
  options.certFile   = options.certFile || {};
  options.keyFile    = options.keyFile || {};
  options.timeout    = options.timeout || 0;

  const opt = {
    hostname: options.hostname,
    port: 443,
    path: options.path,
    method: 'GET',
    cert: fs.readFileSync(options.certFile),
    key: fs.readFileSync(options.keyFile),
    headers: {'AID': options.aftaleId,
              'TID': uuidv4(),
              'RID': uuidv4()
             },
    };

  opt.agent = new https.Agent(opt);

  try {
    const r = await httpsGet(opt, options.timeout);
    return (r.statusCode === options.statusCode && r.body.includes(options.string)) ? 1 : 0;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

function httpsGet(opts, timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.get(opts, (res) => {
      let body = '';
      res.on('data', (data) => {
        body += data.toString();
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve({body, statusCode: res.statusCode});
      });
    });

    req.setTimeout(timeout, function() {
      req.destroy('error');
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
      reject(e);
    });
  });
};
```

**getSecureString.test.js**

```
const getSecureString = require('./getSecureString');
const https = require('https');

jest.mock('https');

describe("getSecureString ", () => {
  describe('when httpsGet returns expected statusCode and body includes expected string', () => {
    let result;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      https.get.mockResolvedValue({
        body: 'xyz secret_string xyz',
        //res.statusCode: 200
      })
      result = await getSecureString({
        hostname:   'encrypted.google.com',
        path:       '/',
        string:     'secret_string',
        statusCode: 200,
        aftaleId:   1234,
        certFile:   './test.crt',
        keyFile:    './test.key',
        timeout:    1000,
      })
    });

    it('should return 1', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(1)
    })
  });

  describe('when httpsGet returns expected statusCode and body includes expected string', () => {
    let result;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      https.get.mockResolvedValue({
        body: 'xyz secret_string xyz',
        //res.statusCode: 200
      })
      result = await getSecureString({
        hostname:   'encrypted.google.com',
        path:       '/',
        string:     'not_secret_string',
        statusCode: 201,
        aftaleId:   1234,
        certFile:   './test.crt',
        keyFile:    './test.key',
        timeout:    1000,
      })
    });

    it('should return 0', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(0)
    })
  });

  describe("when an exception is thrown", () => {
    let result;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      // mockRejected value returns rejected promise
      // which will be handled by the try/catch
      https.get.mockRejectedValue({
        body: 'xyz secret_string xyz',
        //res.statusCode: 200
      })
      result = await getSecureString();
    })

    it('should return -1', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(-1)
    })
  });

});
```

## Question

Can anyone figure out why I get the above error, and how I can mock both `body` and `res.statusCode` in `https.get()`?

Comment: Here is a [working example](https://repl.it/@StefanTeneff/jest-playground-5#getSecureString.test.js), but I can probably describe them tomorrow if there's anything unclear :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I have a question =) I have now added the output of `httpsGet()` as a file at https://repl.it/@SandraSchlichti/jest-playground-6#getSecureString.test.js . I imagine that it wouldn't make much of a difference if I included that or just `string:     'not_secret_string'`, but seeing you have used 3 `dataCallback()`s, I begin to think using the content from `httpsGet.mockResponseData.json` won't be that easy?

Comment: Btw. How did you trigger a chat link?

Comment: I've created a room and pasted the link in the comment. Otherwise SO prompts you to move the conversation in the chat after the 7th or 8th comment

Comment: Ok, should there be a chat link in the comments here?

Comment: and about the multiple triggering of the `dataCallback()` I've done it just as an example, because the callback in the implementation is supposed to concatenate the body with all of the data that's provided by the event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224726/discussion-between-sandra-schlichting-and-teneff).